Most elegant way to compute $\begin{vmatrix} a & b & c \\ a^2 & b^2 & c^2 \\(b+c)^2 & (c+a)^2 & (a+b)^2 \end{vmatrix}$?

Most elegant way to compute \begin{vmatrix} a & b & c \\ a^2 & b^2 & c^2 \\(b+c)^2 & (c+a)^2 & (a+b)^2 \end{vmatrix}?

The result is $D = (a+b+c)^2(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)$.
How do you compute it without expanding everything?

Just subtract first column from the other two, the factors $b-a$ and $c-a$ appear easily.

Subtracting row 2 from row 3, we have
$$\begin{vmatrix} a & b & c \\ a^2 & b^2 & c^2 \\(b+c)^2 - a^2 & (c+a)^2 - b^2 & (a+b)^2 - c^2 \end{vmatrix}.$$
Next, spotting the difference of two squares, we get a common factor in row 3:
$$(a+b+c)\begin{vmatrix} a & b & c \\ a^2 & b^2 & c^2 \\b+c-a & c+a-b & a+b-c \end{vmatrix}$$
Add row 1 to row 3:
$$(a+b+c)\begin{vmatrix} a & b & c \\ a^2 & b^2 & c^2 \\b+c & c+a & a+b \end{vmatrix}$$
Subtract column 1 from columns 2 and 3:
$$(a+b+c)\begin{vmatrix} a & b - a & c - a \\ a^2 & b^2 - a^2 & c^2 - a^2 \\b+c & -(b-a) & -(c-a) \end{vmatrix}$$
This equals
$$(a+b+c)(b-a)(c-a)\begin{vmatrix} a & 1 & 1 \\ a^2 & a+b & a+c \\b+c & -1 & -1 \end{vmatrix}$$
Adding row 1 to row 3:
$$(a+b+c)(b-a)(c-a)\begin{vmatrix} a & 1 & 1 \\ a^2 & a+b & a+c \\a+b+c & 0 & 0 \end{vmatrix}$$
Expanding along the last row, we easily get
$$(a+b+c)^2(b-a)(c-a)(b-c).$$

Add $2(a+b+c)$ times the first row to the last one.
Then subtract the second row from the last one.
You get
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c \\
a^2 & b^2 & c^2 \\
(a+b+c)^2 & (a+b+c)^2 & (a+b+c)^2 
\end{vmatrix} \\
=(a+b+c)^2 
\begin{vmatrix}
a & b & c \\
a^2 & b^2 & c^2 \\
1 & 1 & 1 
\end{vmatrix}
$$
Now swap the first and the third row and then the second and the third to get
$$
(a+b+c)^2 \begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
a & b & c \\
a^2 & b^2 & c^2
\end{vmatrix}
$$
Using the known formula for the determinant of the Vandermonde-matrix, we get the result.

What's the known formula for vandermonde? I don't know such thing exists

You can find it here: Vandermonde matrix.  Without this formula, the most elegant way to compute the determinante is probably using one of the other answers that subtract columns from each other, instead of performing row manipulations.

$$D=\begin{vmatrix} a & b & c \\ a^2 & b^2 & c^2 \\(b+c)^2 & (c+a)^2 & (a+b)^2 \end{vmatrix}$$
Now we can do column operations $C_2=C_2-C_1$ and $C_3=C_3-C_1$
$$\begin{align}D&=\begin{vmatrix} a & b-a & c-a \\ a^2 & b^2-a^2 & c^2-a^2 \\(b+c)^2 & (c+a)^2-(b+c)^2 & (a+b)^2-(b+c)^2 \end{vmatrix}\\ \ \\&=\begin{vmatrix} a & b-a & c-a \\ a^2 & (b-a)(b+a) & (c-a)(c+a) \\(b+c)^2 & (a-b)(a+b+2c) & (a-c)(a+2b+c) \end{vmatrix}\end{align}$$
Now we can divide $C_2$ by $b-a$ and $C_3$ by $c-a$ to get
$$\begin{align}D&=(b-a)(c-a)\begin{vmatrix} a & 1 & 1 \\ a^2 & b+a & c+a \\(b+c)^2 & -(a+b+2c) & -(a+2b+c) \end{vmatrix}\end{align}$$
Now we can do the row operation $R_3=R_3-R_2$ then $R_2=R_2-a\times R_1$
$$\begin{align}D&=(b-a)(c-a)\begin{vmatrix} a & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & b & c \\(a+b+c)(b+c-a) & -2(a+b+c) & -2(a+b+c) \end{vmatrix}\end{align}$$
And now we can take $2(a+b+c)$ out and do $C_2=C_2-C_3$ then $R_3=R_3+R_1$
$$\begin{align}D&=2(b-a)(c-a)(a+b+c)\begin{vmatrix} a & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & b-c & c \\{b+c+a\over2} & 0 & 0 \end{vmatrix}\end{align}$$
And after simply expanding the det we get
$$\begin{align}D&=(a-b)(b-c)(c-a)(a+b+c)^2\end{align}$$
